# Error publishing xcode/swift app too appstore - libsqlite.tbd doesn't have the correct file type

Tags: swift, sqlite, app-store, xcode8, itunes

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 . application tested in iPhone & iPad truly but now I am trying to upload app on iTunes Connect.

In application loader an error appearing as below:

> Invalid Swift Support....`/libsqlite3.tbd` doesn't have the correct file
>   type fore this location. Ensure you're using the correct file, ...

Can anybody help me?